# Turning off log rotation with ruby logging gem

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have some code I am maintaining that is using the logging ruby gem.  I would like to use the linux logrotate tool instead of the gem to rotate the logs.  I'm using it inside some custom code to create separate log streams.

```rb
require 'logging'
[...]
def create_logger(name)
   logger = Logging.logger[name]
```

Is there a way I can turn off log rotation after the logger object is created?

`logger.age = 0` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The source code has [good documentation](https://github.com/ruby/logger/blob/master/lib/logger.rb#L283), which only mentions setting rotation strategy on initialization, I don't think changing an existing instance's rotation strategy is a good idea as it could have unintended consequences.

But, you could close the existing logger with [`logger.close`](https://github.com/ruby/logger/blob/master/lib/logger.rb#L57) and reopen it later with [`logger.reopen`](https://github.com/ruby/logger/blob/master/lib/logger.rb#L617).